# Sharepoint Tasks, SVN Repository, Visual Studio / Tortoise / ANKHSVN Tie

Tags: visual-studio, svn, sharepoint, tortoisesvn, ankhsvn

## Background:

I work for a company who utilizes Sharepoint for Task Management.  We develop with Visual Studio 2008 and Visual Studio 2010.  Our code repository is SVN and I have Tortoise SVN intalled as well as the ankhSVN plugin for Visual Studio.

## Question:

Is there a way to tie these systems together.  I would like my commits to SVN to be tied to their respective SharePoint task.  And total bonus feature would be to push a revision history back to the task to be listed so our Client could see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

+1 for going on ALM solution.

If [TFS](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/team-foundation-server/overview) is not an option, have a look at [Sublime](http://www.sublimesvn.com/blog/2010/08/integrating-subversion-with-sharepoint/). Not a free solution but not overly priced either.

Comment: Sublime looks pretty nice.  I am going to leave this open for a while but through my searches sublime was about all I found as well.

Answer (score 1):

AnkhSVN has an extension api that third parties can use to integrate their ALM solutions into AnkhSVN.

There are CollabNet, Redmine and Jira plugins available and on our site there is a C# sample application that makes it easy to create your own integration.

If you just want an easy to use link to your workitem tracker you can just setup the TortoiseSVN properties for that. If you then click on a link to an issue you can just navigate to the issue in your webbrowser.